# Why doesn't Razor view properly call ToString() on my struct

Tags: razor

I have a Money class that looks like this (simplified):

```
public class Money
{
    private readonly decimal _amount;

    public decimal Amount
    {
        get { return _amount; }
    }

    public Money(decimal amount)
    {
        _amount = amount;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _amount.ToString("c2");
    }

    public static implicit operator Money(decimal value)
    {
        return new Money(value);
    }
}
```

In my Razor view, I want to render a money value like this:

```
<p>This is my money value:
    @Model.MyNullableMoneyValue
</p>
```

When I run the View, instead of using the Money struct's ToString() method which should result in something like "$10.00", it renders as though it was calling ToString() on the decimal amount, i.e. like "10.0000".

Adding ToString() myself fixes the issue:

```
<p>This is my money value:
    @Model.MyNullableMoneyValue.ToString()
</p>
```

Why? What's going on?